# C++ passing array of pointers of methods to a method as argument

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, methods

I have the following typedef:

```
typedef void (*Subs)(uint8_t button);
```

And for example this array:

```
 const Subs settings_sub[] = {Settings_SVA, BackToRoot};
 const uint8_t settings_size = 2;
```

Where "Settings_SVA, BackToRoot" are methods of the type:

```
void Method_name(uint8_t button){}
```

Now my problem is a different method, that uses these arrays and simply cycles through them:

```
void MoveThroughItems(uint8_t button, uint8_t counter, uint8_t limit, ??? subitems) {}
```

I don't know what to correctly place for the '???' for subitems, which is the above mentioned array.

Currently I use Subs subitems[] which results in an error:

```
invalid conversion from 'void (* const*)(uint8_t)' to 'void (**)(uint8_t)
```

And using "void (* const*)(uint8_t)" as the type results in:

```
error: expected ',' or '...' before 'subitems'
error: 'subitems' was not declared in this scope
```

I am pretty much stuck here, maybe I missed something simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `const` - `const Subs subitems[]`  because you defined `const Subs settings_sub[] = {Settings_SVA, BackToRoot};`.